# A faster way to evaluate 2D-array items than nested for loops?

Tags: python

I'm using python 2.7

I have a 2-dimensional array that is several hundred elements on each axis. Each element is either '0', or '255' I need to look at each element and write a '0' or '1' into a different array that has the same dimensions. Currently I have a nested for-loop structure iterating over the rows and columns.

This is turning out to be really, really slow. What is a better implementation? What if I multiplied the matrix by a constant 1/255. This would keep the zeros as zeros, and convert the 255 to '1'. but this is just trading the loops for an enormous number of multiplies, which probably has its own speed issues.

Thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like you need [`Numpy.ndarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) here.

Comment: What do you do with the new array? Is there any way around needing `1`s in it?

Comment: Multiplying by 1./255 is not a brilliant idea. Firstly you'd still have to do the copying if you want to keep the old array and you'd change from `int` to `float`

Comment: What do you actually have? A list of lists (`foo[y][x]`), a flat list or array.array (`foo[y * w + x]`), a dict with tuple keys (`foo[x,y]`)? For a flat representation, `[int(bool(x)) for x in foo]` would do the trick.

Comment: can you show us your code? and several hundreds of elements in two dimensions, that should take on  milliseconds to execute? so i dont get the "slowness" ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd also use numpy.array for fast array manipulation, here's an example :

```
import numpy as np
# Create an example array of shape (100, 100) filled with either 0 or 255
a = 255*np.random.randint(2, size=10000).reshape(100,100)

# Transform it as you want
1*(a==255)
```